# AWS RDS ERROR 1305 (42000): FUNCTION bairways.get_arrival does not exist

Tags: mysql, sql, stored-procedures, amazon-rds

I am trying to run my sql query from a sql source file on AWS RDS mysql database. But I am getting the above error when trying to create a procedure.

Here is the part of the sql file where I define the procedure **get_arrival**

```
DROP FUNCTION IF EXISTS get_arrival;
DELIMITER $$

CREATE FUNCTION get_arrival(
    val_route_id int(10),
    val_departure_datetime datetime,
    val_delay double
    )
RETURNS datetime
BEGIN
    DECLARE route_duration varchar(10);
    DECLARE val_arrival_datetime datetime;
    
    SELECT duration INTO route_duration
    FROM Route WHERE route_id=val_route_id;

    set val_arrival_datetime = ADDDATE(ADDTIME(val_departure_datetime, route_duration), INTERVAL val_delay MINUTE);
    RETURN val_arrival_datetime;
END $$
DELIMITER;
```

On my local machine using **xampp mysql server** I was able to execute the above query without any exception.

How can I solve this issue?

Comment: On which line do you get this error?

Comment: @Shadow Here's the gist to the complete sql: https://gist.github.com/nimsara66/abdd222a80915e3a9e7c8494eaf5fc4d. The error originated at line 613.